# Set of solutions to $\sqrt{x^2}=-x$

Tags: roots

The question is:

> The set of all real numbers x such that $$\sqrt{x^2}=-x$$ consists of:
>
> A: zero only
>
> B: nonpositive real numbers only
>
> C: positive real numbers only
>
> D: all real numbers
>
> E: no real numbers

I chose D because the root of any number gives a $+$ and $-$, so if $x$ is a positive real number eg. $2$ then $\sqrt{4^2}= -2$
and if $x$ is a negative real number eg. $-2$ then $\sqrt{4^2} = 2$

But the answer is B, can someone explain this to me? I'm presuming that in maths when they have an equation with $\sqrt{\cdot}$ they mean $+$ unless there is a $-$ or plus/minus sign. Can someone confirm this?

Comment: Are you taking the root first and then squaring? or other way around?

Comment: Why do you say "if $x$ is negative, eg. $2$"? $2$ is positive!

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: With `√x^2` do you mean `\sqrt{x^2}` that is $\sqrt{x^2}$...? Or rather `(\sqrt x)^2` that is $(\sqrt x)^2$...?

Comment: I have changed it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The square root of a nonnegative real number $x$ is, by definition, the **positive** real number $a$ such that $a^2 = x$. As a consequence, you have the property
$$\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$$
which reduces your question to: *what real numbers satisfy*
$$|x| = -x$$
If you know how the absolute value works (or: check its definition), this shouldn't be hard anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Let's use your example.

Putting $x=2$ in the given function we get $\sqrt {2^2}=-2$.

But we know that square roots always produce positive numbers.

Hence $\sqrt {2^2}$ should be equal to $2$. Therefore if $x$ is positive, then the given equation won't work.

Now, putting $x=-2$ in the given equation we get $\sqrt {(-2)^2}=-(-2)=2.$ Which is true since $\sqrt {(-2)^2}=\sqrt {2^2}=\sqrt 4=2$

So in other words, the given equation holds for all negative real numbers and Zero.

Hence B is the correct option.